# Mongo not release system memory

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongo database, after processing bulk of data mongo not release the system memory  quickly. After 1 or 2 days it will release the system memory if not using the mongo database.

Comment: How exactly did you determine this?

Comment: Why would you want a database to not use as much system memory as it can get? That's it's job, and how it does things faster than accessing slower I/O all of the time. Also off-topic, and should be on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com). But unaltered, this question would just be closed there.

Comment: @robertklep: When we again process the file it throws error that "too many files open".

Comment: If MongoDB is throwing that error, you need to read this: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/ulimit/ (FWIW, that's not a memory issue).

Comment: After processing heavy data mongo use 2 gb system memory and i will release this memory after 1 0r 2 day. If we restart the mongod then release the memory.How to release the memory after completion of process.Please suggest the solution.